# Load data from database/model with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm creating a Google Maps application. I need to load location data from a database with Ajax, so I can show these data every x seconds. I'm using CodeIgniter/PHP. This is what I got:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <title>Simple Map</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var map;
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                });


                httpCall();
            }

            function httpCall($http) {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json"
                })
                        .success(function (data) {
                            for (var i = 0, len = markers.length; i < len; ++i) {
                                var myLatLng = {lat: markers[i].lat, lng: markers[i].lng};

                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: {
                                        lat: parseFloat(markers[i].lat),
                                        lng: parseFloat(markers[i].lng)
                                    },
                                    map: map
                                });
                            }
                        })
            }

        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the User/marks function is:

```
function marks() {
    echo json_encode($this->user_model->get_marks());
}
```

user_model get marks function is:

```
        function get_marks() {
            $sql = "select lat,lng 
from tbl_locations";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
        }
```

My error is:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Apparently I pass the data incorrectly, but what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Store your json result in an array

```
function marks() {
    echo json_encode(array('data'=>$this->user_model->get_marks()));
}
```

and try to print the result of data by using console.log(data) in your ajax result.

Comment: I still get "ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't define **data** variable, which you are passing through **data: data,** 
 You have to define it in function httpCall($http) then pass it in ajax function